# simple TableView not displaying data

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am a beginner, learning how to do tableViews. I followed everything in my book, but my table View is not being populated. Shouldn't it display the word "Testing" for three rows here? My tableview Outlet is connected, and I enabled the delegate and datasource. What am I missing here? After all, I am following a book.

```
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource Methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if( nil == cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Testing";
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView *)tv numberofRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate Methods

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

here is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CLViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

Comment: Did you implement the `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` method?

Comment: @esker: You need not implement that method (if you have one section), the default method returns `1`.

Comment: Oops, I was supposed to write my comment below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your data source method, `numberofRowsInSection` should be
`numberOfRowsInSection`.

As a consequence, the default implementation of `numberOfRowsInSection` is called and
that returns `0`.

Comment: @GeorgeFriday: You are welcome. - Btw.: Did you declare your class (or class extension) as conforming to the `<UITableViewDataSource>` protocol? Because then Xcode autocompletion should work with the data source methods.

Comment: I did... I guess I just ignored autocompletion and just typed away, looking at my tutorial book.